# error help! syntax and OnItemSelectedListener

Tags: android, syntax, android-spinner

OK, so I'm pretty new to this, but I'm getting it. I just ran into this error and I have seen other people have had the same problem, but the standard fix (clean) doesn't work for me. I have no clue how to fix these errors! HELP PLEASE!

first error:

on `sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {` in my else if statement I keep geting this error:

The type new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.onNothingSelected(AdapterView)

I have the onNothingSelected there, and it works in my if statement, I mean all I did was copy and paste and edit.

second error:

on `});` at the end of my else if statement i get the error:

Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement

but everything is there. the statement is completed!

```
sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    public void onItemSelecteds(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int arg2, long arg3) {


             String reg_select = (sp1.getSelectedItem().toString());
                 if (reg_select.contentEquals("Southwest")){
                     sp2.setAdapter(sw_cit_adp); 
                     sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                             String sw_cit_select = (sp2.getSelectedItem().toString());
                             if (sw_cit_select.contentEquals("Lake Charles")){
                                 sp3.setAdapter(sw_lake_charles_adp); }

                             else if (sw_cit_select.contentEquals("Iowa")){
                                 sp3.setAdapter(sw_iowa_adp); }


                            ;}

                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            };});}

                 else if (reg_select.contentEquals("South Central")){
                         sp2.setAdapter(sc_cit_adp); 
                         sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                 String sc_cit_select = (sp2.getSelectedItem().toString());
                                 if (sc_cit_select.contentEquals("Lafayette")){
                                     sp3.setAdapter(sc_lafayette_adp); }

                                 else if (sc_cit_select.contentEquals("Gueydan")){
                                     sp3.setAdapter(sc_gueydan_adp); }


                                ;}
                                public void onNothingSelected(
                                        AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }



                                ;
                               });
                         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that method in the wrong place.  You can't have an item selected and nto select anything, that's non-sensical.

You need to put the method under the listener, like the `onItemSelected`, but not inside `onItemSelected`.

This is what it should (basically) look like:

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int pos, long id) {
        // Your code to do something with the selected item
        }
    });
```

Oh, and you need to use the exact method name... it's `onItemSelected` **not** `onItemSelecteds`

Comment: See my edit.. you need to use the proper method names and close the call properly ( `});` not just `}` ).

Comment: and on the onItemSelecteds fix I now get Duplicate method onItemSelected(AdapterView<?>, View, int, long) in type new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){}

Comment: Yes, you can only have that method once per listener

Comment: I understand that, but I want sp2 to populate dependent on the selection made in sp1, and sp3 to populate dependent on the selection made in sp2. It works fine for the if statement, its the else if statement that is giving me trouble. That is why I don't understand it. The if statement is PERFECT, works how it is supposed to so I copy and pasted the code for the if else and edited it in the correct places to load the desired info, and it craps out. before I had all these errors I was getting a force close when I selected Lafayette, but I figured it was because I didnt have an action defined

Comment: for the else if statement, so i went to go add that and started getting errors.

Comment: ok, I just copy and pasted it all and reworked it, and the errors are gone. but now I am getting a force close again when South Central is selected. I will work on that. Thank you for your help. I will probably be posting a question about it with my logcat.